# Rails: Why am I getting the ActiveRecord error "missing FROM-clause entry for table"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models in a Ruby (not Rails) application: `Bill` and `BillItem`. I'm using ActiveRecord to try to find all `Bills` that have a `BillItem` with a `user_id` property of `1`.

**bill.rb**

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bill_items
end
```

**bill_item.rb**

```
class BillItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bill
end
```

I've tried the following ActiveRecord queries:

```
Bill.where('bill_items.user_id = 1')
Bill.where(bill_items: { user_id: 1 })
```

Both of which result in the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry
for table 'bill_items'

LINE 1: SELECT "bills".* FROM "bills"  WHERE "bill_items"."user_id" ...
                                             ^

: SELECT "bills".* FROM "bills"  WHERE (bill_items.user_id = 34)
```

There are similar questions on SO, but most seem to a naming issue (referring to `bill_item` instead of `bill_items`). I'm stumped, what's going on here?

Comment: You need to JOIN `bill_items` before you can reference it.

Comment: Is the user_id field in bill_items or bills ?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in a comment, you need to join in the other table:

```
Bill.joins(:bill_items).where('bill_items.user_id' => 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same challenge when working on a Rails 6 application.

I had a model `Product` that belongs to another model named `Badge`.

**Product Model**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :badge
end
```

**Badge Model**

```
class Badge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
end
```

I wanted to define a scope where only **products will badge name `Fair`** will be shown, however, I was encountering an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry
for table 'badges'
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

You can use the `where` clause in an Active Record relation to retrieve filtered data from multiple tables

```
scope :best_sellers, -> { Product.joins(:badge).where('badges.name': 'Fair') }
```

OR

You can use the `find_by` clause in an Active Record relation to retrieve specific data from multiple tables

```
scope :best_sellers, -> { Product.joins(:badge).find_by('badges.name': 'Fair') }
```

**Note**:

1. If a query matches multiple records, `find_by` will fetch only the first one and ignore the others. It implements `LIMIT 1` by default in its queries.
2. Letters/values/inputs are case-sensitive. `Fair` and `fair` are totally different letters/values/inputs, so ensure you doublecheck your values letters/values/inputs to avoid unnecessary time wastage on debugging.

**Scope Duplication**

If you need to use this scope in another model, say, `Home`, instead of duplicating it this way:

```
class Home < ApplicationRecord
    scope :best_sellers, -> { Product.joins(:badge).where('badges.name': 'Fair') }
end
```

You could simply use this concept to make it **DRY**:

```
class Home < ApplicationRecord
  # This scope are from the Product model
  scope :best_products, -> { best_sellers }
end
```

This helps you to avoid duplication of code, so that you can make code changes just in one place.

You can read up **Rails documentation** more on [Understanding The Method Chaining](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#understanding-the-method-chaining)

That's all

**I hope this helps**